# Angular Http Get dont set the value on startup

Tags: json, angular, http, get

i wanted to simulate a http request by reading an Json File and its stored data. Here is how i tryed it:

Data.json:

```
 { "jsonData": {

"data": [{ "age": "18", "name": "bernd", "gender": "1", "lid": 123},
{ "age": "18", "name": "bernd", "gender": "1", "lid": 123},
{ "age": "15", "name": "bernd", "gender": "1", "lid": 123},
{ "age": "18", "name": "marting", "gender": "1", "lid": 123},
{ "age": "25", "name": "bernd", "gender": "1", "lid": 123},
{ "age": "29", "name": "bernd", "gender": "1", "lid": 123},
{ "age": "18", "name": "mike", "gender": "1", "lid": 123},
{ "age": "45", "name": "bernd", "gender": "1", "lid": 123},
{ "age": "18", "name": "bernd", "gender": "1", "lid": 123}
]}}
```

DataService:

```
arrayOfData: arraysFormat[][] = [];
data: arrayFormat[] = [];

getServers() {
return this.http.get('../assets/Data.json')
.subscribe((res: Response) => {
  this.data = res.json().jsonData.data as arrayFormat[];
} );
this.arraysOfData = [this.data];
}


getData(listId:string): Observable<ObjectFormat[]>{
let returningData:arrayFormat[] = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arraysOfData.length;i++){
if (this.arrayOfData[i][0].lid == listId) {
returningData[i] = this.arraysOfData[i]
  }
}
return of(returningData);
}
```

DataComponent:

```
ngOnInit(){
this.DataService.getServers();
this.getField();
this.getData();
this.createNumber();
this.SetNumbers();
this.DataService.setArray(this.fieldArray); 
}

getData(){
const listID = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('lid');
this.DataService.getData(listID)
.subscribe(data => this.data = data);
}
```

Now my problem is as i start the app, the "data" property of DataService is always empty and just gets filled after i do sth else at runtime. But as its empty [] on startup, i always getting an error, till i do sth else in the app.

I hope you guys can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asynchronous call doesn't work in synchronous way. You kept `this.arraysOfData` assignment outside `http` call subscribe, so obviously it will evaluate before ajax call completes and initially it will have `undefined` value. You could play with `Observable` and return data from `getData` method itself and `getServers` method will get called from `getData`.

```
arrayOfData: arraysFormat[][] = [];
data: arrayFormat[] = [];

getServers() {
  return this.http.get('../assets/Data.json')
  .map((res: Response) => {
     return res.json().jsonData.data as arrayFormat[];
  }).do(data => this.arraysOfData = [data]);
}


getData(listId:string): Observable<ObjectFormat[]>{
 let returningData:arrayFormat[] = [];
 return getServers().map(data => {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.arraysOfData.length; i++){
       if (this.arrayOfData[i][0].lid == listId) {
           returningData[i] = this.arraysOfData[i]
       }
    }
    return returningData;
 });
}
```

**DataComponent**:

```
ngOnInit(){
  //below call is unnecessary now
  //this.DataService.getServers();
  this.getField();
  this.getData();
  this.createNumber();
  this.SetNumbers();
  this.DataService.setArray(this.fieldArray); 
}

getData(){
   const listID = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('lid');
   this.DataService.getData(listID)
   .subscribe(data => this.data = data);
}
```

Comment: Is there maybe a way to tell the code to wait till the request is done? This seems a bit messy for me, and i still couldnt get it to work with this code either.

Comment: Why *This seems a bit messy for you*?? and what do you mean by this *still couldnt get it to work with this code either*? I can't help you better if you don't tell me exact problem with details

Comment: I mean as a newbie in Angular i need some time to understand every step, nothing wrong about how its written. I used it but this.data never (or not in right time) gets filled with values. I think it works for you because your code dont use the this.data object array afterwards.

Comment: @Kamui any error you can see in the developer console(check by using F12)

Comment: First i had an error with "lid has no property" then i changed the code `getServers() {
  return this.http.get('../assets/Data.json')
  .map((res: Response) => {
     return **this.data** = res.json().jsonData.data as arrayFormat[];
  }).do(data => this.arraysOfData = [this.data]);
}  now the data object array gets filled correctly, but im getting an " "Get 'localhost/4200/null 404 (Not Found)". I call the "this.data" object Array afterwards with a method in the component, does it also get in conflict with the asynchron request?

Comment: @Kamui can you please `console.log(listID )` value of `const listID = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('lid');`

Comment: It returns "54321", so the correct value from the current url.

Comment: Nice, now it works! Thanks alot for your help and patience :)